# How to set QPalette back to default system palette?

Tags: qt, qt5, color-scheme, qstyle, qpalette

I start my application initially in a dark color theme according to [this](https://gist.github.com/QuantumCD/6245215) example.

I would like to make possible for users, to switch back to their current default system color profiles of their operating system (as I start that application without setting QPalette). Is that posssible?

Comment: You may save current palette, before changing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible way is just use default settings and parameters:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qApp->setPalette(this->style()->standardPalette());
    qApp->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("WindowsVista"));
    qApp->setStyleSheet("");
}
```

But this way has some limitation: we need some `QWidget` for setting palette, in my way I use `this` poiter to `QMainWindow`, however it is not so serious problem i think.

Comment: You can use qApp->setPalette(QApplication::style()->standardPalette()); to avoid the need for "this" pointer.

Comment: or just `qApp->setStyle(qApp->style()->standardPalette());`, the, in my eyes, most intuitive one